# Inserting literal values along with razor into javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to insert quotes AND a value inside a javascript function.
I'm doing this through a foreach method call.

```
@foreach (DateEarningsViewClass d in Model.dateEarnings) {
                 @d.date.ToShortDateString()
             }
```

The issue is that I want to insert around each date, but I get all sorts of errors when I attempt doing so. How can I do this?

What I essentially wanna display is:

```
@foreach (DateEarningsViewClass d in Model.dateEarnings) {
                     "@d.date.ToShortDateString()", 
                 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this:

```
@foreach (DateEarningsViewClass d in Model.dateEarnings) {
   @Html.Raw("\"" + d.date.ToShortDateString() + "\"")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  tag.

```
@foreach (DateEarningsViewClass d in Model.dateEarnings) {
    <text>"</text>
    @d.date.ToShortDateString()        
    <text>"</text>
}
```